# Javascript stops working when add another javascript code

Tags: javascript

I am using this js code to validate a proper email is enetered into a form. If not, an warning box pops up.

```
function validateForm() {   
    var valid = true;
    var errMsg = "";
    var email = document.emailform.email.value;
    //var fname = document.emailform.fname.value;
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

   //if(fname.length <= 0) {
      //valid = false;
      //errMsg += "Please provide a valid first name.\n";
   //}
   if(email.length <= 0) {
      valid = false;
      errMsg += "Email address is required.\n";
   } else {
      if (!filter.test(email)) {
         valid = false;
         errMsg += "Please provide a valid email address.\n";
      }
   }   
   if (errMsg.length > 0) {
      alert(errMsg);
      return false;
   }
   }
```

Before my closing  I have this...

```
<script>$('#awform').submit(validateForm);</script>
```

That works just fine.

I have another javascript code that I generally enter before the closing body tag, which works fine under normal circumstances.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> cbr202=Math.random()*10000000000000000;document.write('<scr'+'ipt language="JavaScript" src="http://mywebsite.com/track/static/landing.php?lpip=123&202cb='+cbr202+'" type="text/javascript"></scr' + 'ipt>'); </script>
```

This last piece is for a custom analytics program I use.

The problem I'm running into is that when I use the two scripts together, the validation no longer works.

So I do...

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> cbr202=Math.random()*10000000000000000;document.write('<scr'+'ipt language="JavaScript" src="http://mywebsite.com/track/static/landing.php?lpip=123&202cb='+cbr202+'" type="text/javascript"></scr' + 'ipt>'); </script>
<script>$('#awform').submit(validateForm);</script>
</body>
```

As requested, here's what the tracking script looks like....

```
function t202Init(){
    //this grabs the cid, but if they set a forced kw, this will be replaced 

    if (readCookie('t202forcedkw')) {
        var cid = readCookie('t202forcedkw');
    } else {
        var cid = t202GetVar('cid');
    }

    var lpip = '<? echo htmlentities($_GET['lpip']); ?>';
    var campid = t202GetVar('campid');
    var OVRAW = t202GetVar('OVRAW');
    var OVKEY = t202GetVar('OVKEY');
    var OVMTC = t202GetVar('OVMTC');
    var c1 = t202GetVar('c1');
    var c2 = t202GetVar('c2');
    var c3 = t202GetVar('c3');
    var c4 = t202GetVar('c4');
    var target_passthrough = t202GetVar('target_passthrough');
    var keyword = t202GetVar('keyword');
    var referer = document.referrer;
    var resolution = screen.width+'x'+screen.height;
    var language = navigator.appName=='Netscape'?navigator.language:navigator.browserLanguage; 
    language = language.substr(0,2); 

    document.write("<script src=\"<?php echo $strProtocol; ?>://<? echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/jump/static/record.php?lpip=" + t202Enc(lpip)
        + "&campid="                + t202Enc(campid)
        + "&cid="               + cid
        + "&OVRAW="                 + t202Enc(OVRAW)
        + "&OVKEY="                 + t202Enc(OVKEY)
        + "&OVMTC="                 + t202Enc(OVMTC)
        + "&c1="                    + t202Enc(c1)
        + "&c2="                    + t202Enc(c2)
        + "&c3="                    + t202Enc(c3)
        + "&c4="                    + t202Enc(c4)
        + "&target_passthrough="    + t202Enc(target_passthrough)
        + "&keyword="               + t202Enc(keyword)
        + "&referer="               + t202Enc(referer)
        + "&resolution="            + t202Enc(resolution)
        + "&language="              + t202Enc(language)
        + "\" type=\"text/javascript\" ></script>"
    );

}

function  t202Enc(e){
    return encodeURIComponent(e);

}

function  t202GetVar(name){
    get_string = document.location.search;         
     return_value = '';

     do { 
        name_index = get_string.indexOf(name + '=');

        if(name_index != -1) {
            get_string = get_string.substr(name_index + name.length + 1, get_string.length - name_index);

            end_of_value = get_string.indexOf('&');
            if(end_of_value != -1) {                
                value = get_string.substr(0, end_of_value);                
            } else {                
                value = get_string;                
            }

            if(return_value == '' || value == '') {
                return_value += value;
            } else {
                return_value += ', ' + value;
            }
          }
        } 

        while(name_index != -1)

         //Restores all the blank spaces.
         space = return_value.indexOf('+');
         while(space != -1) { 
            return_value = return_value.substr(0, space) + ' ' + 
            return_value.substr(space + 1, return_value.length);

            space = return_value.indexOf('+');
          }

     return(return_value);

}

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";

}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;

}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}


t202Init();
```

Comment: What error shows up in the console?

Comment: The code seems legit. Most likely the culprit is the custom analytics program.

Comment: No error messages in the console. I am loading jQuery via Google API.

Comment: As general rule, don't use `document.write` unless you're dynamically writing a new popup you just created with using `window.open`.

Comment: Can we see what the tracking JavaScript looks like?

Answer (score 3):

Try switching the order of the two scripts. It seems that the custom analytics program is running `document.write` which is a bit nasty and may cause the rest of the document to not be parsed correctly.

- [Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice).

Answer (score 0):

Your embedded Javascript tags can break your script.  Whenever I try to do a script of the form:

```
<script>
   // Some stuff here
   <script>
       // More stuff here
   </script>
 </script>
```

The script breaks.  Try using a different method to load your analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using jQuery to add the script-tag. You obviously have jQuery included.

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cbr202 = Math.random() *10000000000000000;
    $('head').append('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http://mywebsite.com/track/static/landing.php?lpip=123&202cb='+cbr202+'" />');​
</script>
```

Comment: I tried your code and the analytics isn't work properly with this method.

Comment: There is a single quote missing at the end after >.

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice that. Unfortunately that didn't solve it.

Comment: I'm wondering about that script. I'm really not sure if it's possible to multiplicate with an so long number '10000000000000000'. The max int size afaik is 9007199254740992. See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t